# Documentation inconsistency with new top bar and search box

Tags: bug, top-bar, help-center

According to /help/searching, the way to search is

> Enter search terms in the search box that appears in the upper right corner of every page

However, the search box in the new top bar is in the center-left, not on the right. [A confused user](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10575/44126).